# CKEditor on ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ckeditor

Trying to integrate CKEditor into my asp.net application....
I downloaded both CKEditor 3.x and the CKEditor for ASP.NET control and added the CKEditor reference to the site I also this to the application

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="CKEditor.aspx.cs" Inherits="CKEditor" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="CKEditor.NET" Namespace="CKEditor.NET" TagPrefix="CKEditor" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>CKEditor</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="CKEditor1" BasePath="/ckeditor/" runat="server">
        </CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
    </div>
    </form>
```

but I am getting this error.

```
 CS0426: The type name 'NET' does not exist in the type 'CKEditor'
    <%@ Register Assembly="CKEditor.NET" Namespace="CKEditor.NET" TagPrefix="CKEditor" %>
```

I have searched all through the internet for solutions but it seems I am the only one having this kind of problem...please can someone help.

Comment: Try to add manually copy of DLL file to the bin folder of your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have named your aspx file as `CKEditor`, the same name as your control assembly name having a namespace with same name, so there is a collision.

Try changing your aspx name to something else such as `CKEditorTest.aspx` instead of <strike>`CKEditor.aspx`</strike>

Its always better NOT to name your project, solution, class, control, literal, namespace etc. by any of the reserved keywords or other existing controls, classes, namespaces.

Comment: Hi...Haraman...you rock...and I never knew...that was actually the problem...immediately I changed to CKEditorTest.aspx it worked like magic...thanks man...

Comment: @AdebayoPeterOlaonipekun Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and also [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/306969)

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference to the CKEditor for ASP.NET Control to your website.

In Visual Studio use the Add Reference command and browse to bin\Release\CKEditor.NET.dll file from the unpacked CKEditor for ASP.NET installation package. You can also manually copy the DLL file to the bin folder of your application.

Ref: http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/ASP.NET/Integration_Advanced

Answer (score 0):

I'am using VS 2017 and CKEditor 4.12.
 First, no need to integrate this:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="CKEditor.NET" Namespace="CKEditor.NET" TagPrefix="CKEditor" %>
```

and consequently this:

```
<CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="CKEditor1" BasePath="/ckeditor/" runat="server">
    </CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
```

You only need the following code in your web page:

```
<script src="../Scripts/ckeditor/ckeditor.js" ></script>
     <textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">

        </textarea>
     <div >
        <script>

            CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
</script>
```